# How does Google Calculate AdWord Landing Page Experience?

Tags: google-ads

I've seen tons of articles that give lame advice like "*Makes sure the landing page copy is relevant for your keywords...*"  "*Make sure the layout is clear and the page is easy to navigate...*"  But all this advice strikes me as non-actionable and highly subjective.  I've tried getting help through their call center, but it seems like every engineer I talk to there has a new story about how to improve the landing page experience score, some of the advice has been outright contradictory of previous calls.  So here are some real basic questions:

1. Is the landing page score made by an algorithm (bot) or by a human (editorial score)?
2. I had one engineer suggest that the landing page experience is simply a measure of how long users stay on your site once they navigate to it through an add.  Can anyone verify this.  It certainly would make more sense than any of the other advice I've heard.

Comment: 1. It is algorithm 2. Your phone calls received by marketing people, not by team of engineer who originally develop that algorithm. You're asking for adwords algorithm secret which I believe it is top secret than Google search algorithm. Don't go deep, knowledge is good, but testing should be your first priority.

Comment: It's really a basic question: how do you objectively measure what an 'experience' is?  The items I can imagine could be objectively measured are: page loading time, mobile device support, time spent on the page and number of clicks before exiting the site.  What else could Google measure with a robot?

Comment: 1. Page load time will be various based on products, Amazon page load time is higher than other normal eCommerce website, it is mean it will score higher every time? 2. Mobile responsive webpages are good, but what if I want to target only desktop version for example my product is similar to github. The only thing you should consider is target specific audience and optimize your LP for that audience.

Answer (score 2):

**Landing Page Experience:** It is a combination of several things like:

- The relevance of keywords you are bidding and your content on the website.
- The speed of the website.
- General user experience etc.

**Understand Key Points**

- Before you think about AdWords landing page experience, just think is your website is well optimised what you are offering.
- Make sure your website is well accessible in desktop and mobile.
- Make sure your website loads relatively faster, particularly in mobile.
- Have some mechanism so that user can spend more time on the website. Having Video on the website is a great way to engage with customers.

*If these points are covered then you don't need to bother much in general about Landing Page Experience.*

**You May Consider**

- Based on our test, if you bid higher from the start of the new campaign and have decent ad position and naturally you will see most of the things will work absolutely fine.

**Conclusion: If you address 'key points' and have good bid, it will work absolutely fine.**

Comment: Please tell me how in the world you objectively measure 'General user experience'.

Comment: There are so many ways you can measure better user experience. There can be a course on this. Without complicating, just make your page more relevant and make it easily accessible (Mobile / Desktop) and have a good website structure. Meaning think about key things without going too much into detail unless that is your expertise.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you have no idea what the word 'objective' means.  This is the same non-actionable word-salad I get from the people on the help-lines.

Comment: I am not too sure about your background, but above info is good enough to understand. There are several ways you can measure the user experience effectiveness. If you are really serious about it then i would recommend you to do a course or do in detail research on usability and have a greater understanding of Google Analytics. With the combination of these two, you should be in a good situation to measure user experience and the impact.